# Scroll 2 DIV contents + main content with browser's main scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css

I can't figure out, on how to go around this problem for moving content within two pages + outside content.

I have following layout:

- header + footer
- book
- pages with fixed width and height.

I want to scroll pages content from the main scrollbar without any page scroll bar (like gmail compose example)

The main problem is. book will show after header and if user is using smaller screen resolution, it will show scrollbar to scroll down to see book properly.

Then we have two pages, which content are different from each other and each page can be longer then the other one. so we want to scroll through all the data, before we continue scrolling back to footer again.

`jsFiddle Example:`  http://jsfiddle.net/7vqzF/2/

It would be awesome to solve this from css only.

**Layout Structure**: (solution should have only one main browser scrollbar, to control the pages and outside book content from it.)
[image: layout structure]

Comment: i think remove .outsideBookSpace in this class height your problem solved may be

Comment: @Fags i want to scroll 2 div from main scrollbar. i dont see how removing .outsideBookSpace is the solution for that.

Comment: you want just the .book part to scroll with browser scroll.???

Comment: @maverickosama92 yes .pages to scroll with browser scroll is the main goal, but if header and footer can also be scroll together with it, that would make things work perfectly.

Comment: Question about the image you've attached - is it what you are trying to achieve or is trying to show the error? If it shows the error, please point it out somehow.

Comment: Check this, though I'm not sure if this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/achudars/7vqzF/6/

Comment: @acudars the image is layout structure which we have set and solution is without two pages scrollbar, just main scrollbar should show to control pages data + header & footer

Comment: @acudars Thanks for trying, but i cant use this method. because our book is using turnjs.com flip effect. which changes pages on click and drag. we cant sent position fixed for the pages or outside the pages, because of flip effect it has.

Comment: I am trying to figure out what you want to accomplish, because the way I understand it makes no sense. When the user scrolls the main page scrollbar (as one would normally do to scroll down), you want both the main page to scroll *and* the .pages to scroll? How is this suppose to work on smaller screens? Either the user will never see the footer, or the scrollbar will be huge and the user would have to scroll through the entire book to get to it.

Comment: first scroll to footer, once the footer is reached, then start scrolling both pages with main scroller.

Answer (score 6):

If I got your question right you are looking for the CSS attribute `fixed`. Here is some HTML including CSS that might do exactly what your are after:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin-top: 150px;
      }

      .header {
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: 2px solid lightblue
      }

      .footer {
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: white;
        border-top: 2px solid lightblue
      }

      .book table td {
        vertical-align: top;
      }

      .page1, .page2 {
        border: solid 1px red;
        width: 400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Header</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>contact us</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="book">

      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="page1">
              <h2>Page1</h2>
              scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
              scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
              scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
              ...
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="page2">
              <h2>Page2</h2>
              scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
              scroll from main scrollbar<br/>
              ...
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      My Footer
    </div>     

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot from my browser showing the above HTML:
[image]

The Browser-Scrollbar scrolls only the page1/page2 `<div>` elemtents but not the header and footer elements.

And finally here is the [jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/FFKjY/) for the online-demo.

Comment: here is demo of what i have, please change to previous page, by dragging from the end of the page. to see two page demo: http://v4.globalquran.com/  as you can see, cant use the fixed style on it.

Comment: IMHO it would still be possible to use the fixed style but it would be trickier to implement. But beside the problem with the image-border and the turnjs JavaScript (which wasn't mentioned in the original question) does my example what you expect it to do?

Comment: Yes, but both pages sizes are different in the example you provided. the page size need to be same and scroll size should/can be different and they will scroll both in same time, if they needed to be scrolled. also how is it possible with turnjs and image borders..

Answer (score 1):

Put your header part which needs to be in fixed in separate div and apply these styles.

```
  <div class="fix">
    <h1> Header</h1>
    <menu><ul><li>home</li><li>contact us</li></ul></menu>
    </div>
.fix{
 position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:#FFF;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

for space add another div to bottom of the header

```
<div class="space"></div>
.space{
 width:100%;
 height:150px;   
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vqzF/8/).

Comment: cannot do that with flip book effect, like this one  v4.globalquran.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach with pure CSS and no tables.

**[See online demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/UDH57/)**.

Result:

[image: Example]

It means however that you need to change the document structure a little (I am using HTML5 elements but this can easily be changed into normal divs if required) - as you can see the structure is fairly simple:

```
<header>Header
    <nav>Menu</nav>
</header>

<main>
    <div class="page">
        <h3>Page 1</h3>
        scroll from main scrollbar
        ....
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <h3>Page 2</h3>
            scroll from main scrollbar
            ....
    </div>
</main>

<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Now it's just a matter of styling this so that you can use main scroll-bar to scroll "both" pages. The essential class in this context is:

```
.page {
    float:left;
    margin:70px 10px 50px 10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:45%;
}
```

The important part with the `page` class is that its top and bottom margin is set to match header and footer. This is what makes the two pages visible even if the header and footer are fixed.

The rest of the CSS is just for example:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    font:32px sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    background:#555;
}
nav {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    font:12px sans-serif;
}
footer {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    height:50px;
    background:#555;
}
```

Comment: cannot do this with flip book effect.. like this demo  v4.globalquran.com

Comment: @Basit flip book? Your question says nothing about flip book effect so IMO the post is a bit misleading. And you can use CSS transforms and animations to achieve a flip book effect.

Comment: yes it was my mistake, i didn't manage to explain my situation properly. we already using flip book effect with turn4.js, but this scroll is causing issue for us with it. so dont know how to go around it. using position fixed, is not a solution for it.